# OpenAPI 3 Casting Exception fails to show Api-Docs on localhost

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springfox, springdoc

I am converting our current Swagger configuration from spring fox (Swagger2) to OpenAPI 3.0 (Swagger3), however when I run the SpringBoot project locally and attempt to hit `localhost:8080/v3/api-docs` I get a casting exception:

`{"errors":[{""errorCode":"INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR", "errorDescription":"Internal server error. Unable to process your request", "stackTrace": "java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.package.ObjectInQuestion}]}`

Swagger2 used to work fine but once I introduced the OpenAPI dependencies below, and take out all Swagger2 references, it breaks.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-open-ui</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-open-webmvc-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I even added the webmvc-core alongside to see if that fixed the issue but to no avail. Updated all the tags to the appropriate OpenAPI tags to our API's. Tried with Docket(Swagger2) and OpenAPI(Swagger3) @Beans.

The ObjectInQuestion is not even used in the project, its included as a class model in our common jars so I suspect the issue is with the Swagger3 configuration.

I used the following link to configure OpenAPI, springdoc.org/#migrating-from-springfox

Comment: If you have already swapped all the Swagger annotations and also updated the Docket beans (if any), can you share the code that it was before updating and the code that you landed after updating?

Comment: Provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example - with HelloController that reproduces the problem